# How to correctly import function from src module

Tags: python, pip, python-import, importerror

I have a project folder:

```
project
├── notebooks
│   └── EDA.ipynb
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── data
    │   ├── make_data.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── __init__.py
```

The content in setup.py is:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='src',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.1.0',
    description='',
    author='AG',
    license='MIT')
```

After using `pip install .` from project\ to make my src a python module I can see the module src when I make `conda list`... But when I try to import some function from make_data.py when I am working in EDA.ipynb:

```
from src.data.make_data import some_func
```

I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the virtual environment where you installed 'src' same, where you are trying this.

Pls. run the

```
pip list
```

in that virtual environment to check if 'src' is installed.

Also, pls. check the import statement in the python interpreter of your virtual env.

Comment: When I run `pip list` I can see also the src package in the environment. And when I import src from python interpreter it loads successfully...  In the other attempts from the EDA.ipynb I was also in the correct environmnet.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem, thanks to @Simplecode for the help. It seems that from the terminal I was able to import the module but not from spyder or jupyterlab, despite I was in the same virtual environment. This was because the IDLE were using a different version of python, since they were not installed in the virtualenv. Installing spyder and jupyterlab within the environment solved the import problem.